# Cauliflower : What is happening to these curds?

Tags: diseases, cauliflower

I am growing cauliflower(single plant) at my home in India. I have attached the image of the same. The head formed two weeks ago and i have started to see some pinkish- brown spots on the head.

Can somebody help me in identifying what is happening to the head part? Is it healthy or needs to be picked up?

[image: Cauliflower]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cauliflowers take on many different colors so I don't think it's an issue. They often look purple due to the production of anthocyanins. If you want white, you need to cover the flower to protect against sunlight to blanch them. Many people tie the leaves together, or, if you plant closely the leaves are forced close by crowding.